# Make page fixed not liquid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this page fixed not liquid. When I resize the browser I don't want anything to move. The way it is now when I resize the browser the text collapses. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Help please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Happy Tails</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">


/* body and wrapper */
* {
margin: 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px;
}

body {
background-color: #C15D63;
}

#outer {

}

#container {
width: 50%;
//background-color: #C15D63;
}

/* header */

/* navigation */

/* main content section */
#dog, #cat, #other {
float:left;
width: 750px; 
height: 204px;
margin-left: 50%;
background-color: #E198B2;
padding: 1em;
}

/* dog content */
#dog_float {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 300px;
//bottom: 30px;
left: 376px;
border: 2px solid #222222;
width: 220px;
height: 204px;
}

#dog_inner {

}

#dog h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#dog_inner p.description {
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: .8em;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#dog p {
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 610px;
right: 320px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}


/* cat content */
#cat_float {
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
//right: 30px;
//bottom: 30px;
left: 376px;
border: 2px solid #222222;
width: 220px;
height: 204px;
}

#cat_inner {

}

#cat h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cat_inner p.description {
position: absolute;
top: 269px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: .8em;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#cat p {
position: absolute;
top: 295px;
left: 610px;
right: 320px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

/* other content */
#other_float {
position: absolute;
top: 485px;
//right: 30px;
//bottom: 30px;
left: 376px;
border: 2px solid #222222;
width: 220px;
height: 204px;
}

#other_inner {

}

#other h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 485px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#other_inner p.description {
position: absolute;
top: 504px;
left: 610px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: .8em;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#other p {
position: absolute;
top: 530px;
left: 610px;
right: 320px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

/* footer */
#footer {
clear: both;
border: 3px outset;
background-color: #62587C;
height: 60px;
width: 776px;
margin-left: 50%;
}

#footer_main {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#footer_inner {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.footer_location {
float: left;
font-size: .85em;
text-align: left;
padding: 14px 55px 15px 60px;
}

.footer_social {
float: left;
font-size: .85em;
padding: 18px 5px 0px 35px;
}

#footer img {
padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.footer_contact {
float: right;
font-size: .85em;
text-align: right;
padding: 14px 60px 15px 55px;
}

#footer a:link {
color: black;
}

#footer a:hoover {
color: black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="container">

    <div id="dog">

    <div id="dog_float">
    <img src="beanie.png" alt="Beanie, 10yrs" />
    </div><!--end div dog_float-->

    <div id="dog_inner">
    <h1>Beanie Baby</h1>
    <p class="description">Yorkshire Terrier, Female, 10 years, 5 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->

    <p>
    Beanie Baby was brought into our rescue from Lancaster, PA where she and her two siblings were born to a breeder. When she was born she was the size of an actual beanie baby, hence the name! She was adopted in 2008 to a family of three who loved and cared for her. With some good TLC, Beanie became an outgoing pup who loved everyone and every other animal, but she was a total momma's girl! She loved to snuggle under the blankets and was always there to greet you after a long day at work. Beanie passed away in 2011.
    </p>    
    </div><!--end div dog_inner-->
    </div><!--end div dog-->

    <div id="cat_float">
    <img src="tink.png" alt="Tinkerbell, 18yrs" />
    </div><!--end div cat_float-->

    <div id="cat">

    <div id="cat_inner">
    <h1>Tinkerbell</h1>
    <p class="description">Tabby Short Hair, Male, 18 years, 12 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->
    <p>
    Tinkerbell first came into our rescue 18 years ago. He loved to spend his days outside soaking up the sun and the nights inside sleeping an the foot of someone's bed. Every time Tinkerbell heard a can opener, he came running assuming that he was going to get a helping of tuna. He was a cat that enjoyed his personal space, but had a daily routine to come visit someone for a good scratching. Tinkerbell passed away in 2012.
    </p>
    </div><!--end div cat_inner-->
    </div><!--end div cat-->

    <div id="other">
    <div id="other_float">
    <img src="sadie2.png" alt="Sadie, 1yrs" />
    </div><!--end div other_float-->

    <div id="other_inner">
    <h1>Sadie</h1>
    <p class="description">Hamster, Female, 1 year, 1 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->
    <p>
    Sadie is a beautiful tan/white hamster. She came into our rescue when her first family could not give her the attention she required. In 2010, a family adopted Sadie as their first family pet. The family recognized that just like any other animal, even small caged creatures need love and attention. Sadie loves to go on adventures through the house in her spinning ball and find new paths through her jungle tube maze, which the family constantly adds to. For Sadie, her second chance was the best thing that could have happened to her.
    </p>
    </div><!--end div other_inner-->
    </div><!--end div other-->



<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_inner">
        <p class="footer_location">1234 Forbes Avenue<br />
        Pittsburgh, PA 15213</p><!--end p footer_location-->

        <p class="footer_social">
        <a href="www.petfinder.com"><img src="finder.png" alt="See our animals on Petfinder" /></a>
        <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="Facebook.png" alt="Friend us on Facebook" /></a>
        <a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" /></a>
        <a href="www.youtube.com"><img src="youtube.png" alt="Visit Our YouTube Channel" /></a></p><!--end p footer_social-->

        <p class="footer_contact">Telephone: 512.341.8872<br />
        Email: <a href="mailto:paws+claws@gmail.com">paws+claws@gmail.com</a></p><!--end p footer_contact-->
    </div><!--end div footer_inner-->
</div><!--end div footer-->

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It will help if you make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) in the future. You would get help faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
body {min-width: 750px;}
```

Change the value to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Width:50% is relative. Your size of container will always be 50% of the size of your browser window.

If you want fixed, use width:500px; or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! That's a somewhat painful layout.

You can re-use css styles more than you have, using class instead of id to differentiate.
I didn't bother to add every element you're displaying (some stuff in the footer and the buttons that seem like they should be in the footer)

Your page was 303 lines of text. This example is 93.
Also - you should have a look at the Developer Tools found in browsers - they let you see the bounding-rect of elements and change their styles dynamically - two things that you may find helpful. :)

Key combination Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome & Opera
Key F12 in IE

Or you can often right-click an element then select "Inspect Element"

Enjoy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #C15D63;
}
.page
{
    background-color: #E198B2;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.pageFooter
{
    border: 3px outset;
    background-color: #62587C;
    height: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
.item
{
    margin: 16px;
}

.item img
{
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 204px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-right: 32px;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

h1 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p.description 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='page'>
        <br>

        <div class='item'>
            <img src='item1.png'>
            <h1>Beanie Baby</h1
            <p class="description">Yorkshire Terrier, Female, 10 years, 5 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->
            <p>
            Beanie Baby was brought into our rescue from Lancaster, PA where she and her two siblings were born to a breeder. When she was born she was the size of an actual beanie baby, hence the name! She was adopted in 2008 to a family of three who loved and cared for her. With some good TLC, Beanie became an outgoing pup who loved everyone and every other animal, but she was a total momma's girl! She loved to snuggle under the blankets and was always there to greet you after a long day at work. Beanie passed away in 2011.
            </p>    
        </div>

        <div class='item'>
            <img src='item2.png'>
            <h1>Tinkerbell</h1>
            <p class="description">Tabby Short Hair, Male, 18 years, 12 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->
            <p>
            Tinkerbell first came into our rescue 18 years ago. He loved to spend his days outside soaking up the sun and the nights inside sleeping an the foot of someone's bed. Every time Tinkerbell heard a can opener, he came running assuming that he was going to get a helping of tuna. He was a cat that enjoyed his personal space, but had a daily routine to come visit someone for a good scratching. Tinkerbell passed away in 2012.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='item'>
            <img src='item3.png'>
            <h1>Sadie</h1>
            <p class="description">Hamster, Female, 1 year, 1 lbs.</p><!--end p description-->
            <p>
            Sadie is a beautiful tan/white hamster. She came into our rescue when her first family could not give her the attention she required. In 2010, a family adopted Sadie as their first family pet. The family recognized that just like any other animal, even small caged creatures need love and attention. Sadie loves to go on adventures through the house in her spinning ball and find new paths through her jungle tube maze, which the family constantly adds to. For Sadie, her second chance was the best thing that could have happened to her.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='pageFooter'>
            <p class="footer_location">1234 Forbes Avenue<br />
            Pittsburgh, PA 15213</p><!--end p footer_location-->
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Forgot the ! in !DOCTYPE

Comment: You shouldv'e just edited it...

Comment: No. I'll correct spelling, grammar, punctuation and formatting, but I'd rather not correct people’s code.

Comment: That's an interesting line of distinction. I'd be most curious as to your reasons.

Comment: Code can make or break a script's functionality. If I were to edit your code and break the build [in whichever way] I would look very silly indeed. It's just a principle thing.

Comment: Agree, in the event of a mistake you would appear rather foolish - though the risk is that other times when it's a perfectly obvious and safe fix, you just appear to be a smart-ass. The generally accepted thing to do is to make the change AND make note of the change in the post - anybody following can reverse your action if it proves to be erroneous. Sometimes one must exercise judgement rather than just simply sticking to a script...